# How to setup dev environment for openJDK8 HotSpot VM?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot

I'm trying to setup an environment in which I would be able to change the Hotspot vm GC source code.
I cloned the jdk8 repository as instructed here: http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/
and after a lot of effort succedded in compiling the whole project (including the hotspot project).

I have all the compilation results in a release folder, but couldn't find any executable or any other way to run\use the hotspot vm.

Does someone maybe had a similar experience with this project and can help me figure this out?
Thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the OpenJDK 8 [build instructions](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/raw-file/tip/README-builds.html):

> When the build is completed, you should see the generated binaries and associated files in the j2sdk-image directory in the output directory. In particular, the build/*/images/j2sdk-image/bin directory should contain executables for the OpenJDK tools and utilities for that configuration.

Comment: Thanks. I saw that comment, this directory has many files and I didn't find any instructions that explain how to run any of them, and particularly the hotspot vm. Do you have any idea how to use the hotspot vm specificaly?

Comment: Most of the executables use the JVM (i.e. Hotspot), but the `java` command is probably what you mean.  Run `java -version`.

Comment: This folder has many java related executable files, non of them seems related to the hotspot vm.
When running `java -version` I get the following output:
_openjdk version "1.8.0-internal",
openjdk Runtime Environment (build-1.8.0-internal),
openjdk 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)_

Nothing that indicates a use of the specific vm that runs the hotspot code.
Any idea what file to look for maybe?

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that there is (or should be) a separate "hotspot" executable in a Java JRE or JDK (Oracle or OpenJDK).  There isn't. The `java` command is it.